# Adding filter with map and count in java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There is a list of objects. The requirement is to

1. Add a filter to check if the field is initialized
2. Add a map to fetch a particular field in the list of objects
3. Add a count check with the condition that the count of the field got above should be 1 (unique value in the list).
4. Return the value of the field if the condition 3 is met else return null

Now, I am achieving the above in two steps, filtering out the initialized value list in step 1. In step 2 use this list and find the value in the list if it has unique value, else return `null`

**Facing an issue** when I combine the two It should not be filtering the elements before the count.

```java
List<CarDetails> carDetails = 
   carDetails.stream().filter(
   carDTO -> 
   carDTO.isInitialized(CarDetail.Fields.CAR_ID.getCode())).collect(Collectors.toList());

if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(carDetails))
{
   carId =(carDetails.stream().map(CarlDetail::getCarId).distinct().count() > 1) 
          ? null:carDetails.get(0).getCarId();
}
```

**Eg:**
List `CarDetails-CarId`

```
{3,4,null}  ---o/p= null (since id is not unique)
{3,null}    ---o/p= null (since id is not unique - has 3 and null)
{3,3,3}     ---o/p= 3 (since id is unique)
```

Please let me know how I can achieve the above with the filter got and by not getting null pointer when there is a null value in the list

Comment: Your problem description is not clear.

Comment: The requirements aren't clear

Comment: There is no point in using 3rd party library functions like `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(carDetails)` when you can do a simple `carDetails.isEmpty()`. But in this case, even that check is obsolete, as you can simply do `carId =carDetails.stream().map(CarlDetail::getCarId).distinct().count() == 1? null: carDetails.get(0).getCarId();` But when you don’t need `carDetails` for other purposes, it’s much simpler to collect the ids in the first place: `Set<YourIdType> ids = carDetails.stream().filter(carDTO -> carDTO.isInitialized(CarDetail.Fields.CAR_ID.getCode())).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 1):

I just want to demonstrate what you **could** do with a (pre-filtered) list of objects:

```
list.stream()
   .filter(aPredicate)
   .map(anExtractionFunction)
   .distinct()
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.counting(), c -> c == 1 ? someValue : someFallbackValue))
```

This returns `someValue` if there is only one unique element, otherwise `someFallbackValue`.

Maybe this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to count elements. Since you only care for the ID and need a unique ID, you can simply use

```
carID = carDetails.stream()
    .filter(carDTO -> carDTO.isInitialized(CarDetail.Fields.CAR_ID.getCode()))
    .map(cd -> Optional.ofNullable(cd.getCarId()))
    .reduce((a,b) -> a.equals(b)? a: Optional.empty())
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .orElse(null);
```

Since this operation is only interested in the id, mapping to `getCarId()` before the reduction is straight-forward. But we have to wrap the values into `Optional`s, as `reduce` without an identity value doesn’t support `null` result values.

Then, we reduce all values to a single one. If the ids are equal, we use either of them, otherwise, we replace them with an empty optional. Empty optionals are not equal to non-empty optionals. Two empty optionals are equal, but mapping to either of them leads again to an empty optional. So after mapping empty optionals to `null`, the requirement to map to `null` if any id is `null` is fulfilled automatically.